# Shortest subset sum of arr dynamic programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

My goal is to find the shortest subset of an array that its sum is equal to target. I tried to use the following solution (with dynamic programming):

```
public static List<Integer> bestSum_efficient(int targetSum, int[] numbers) {
    return bestSum_efficient(targetSum, numbers, new HashMap<>());
}

public static List<Integer> bestSum_efficient(int targetSum, int[] numbers, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map) {
    if (map.containsKey(targetSum)) {
        return map.get(targetSum);
    }
    if (targetSum == 0)
        return new ArrayList<>();
    if (targetSum < 0)
        return null;

    List<Integer> shortestCombination = null;
    for (int n : numbers) {
        List<Integer> remainedCombination = bestSum_efficient(targetSum - n, numbers,map);
        if (remainedCombination != null) {
            remainedCombination.add(n);

        if (shortestCombination == null || shortestCombination.size() > remainedCombination .size()) {
                shortestCombination = remainedCombination ;
            }
        }
    }
    map.put(targetSum, shortestCombination);
    return shortestCombination;
}
```

With this code I tried to run the following test:

```
System.out.println(bestSum_efficient(8, new int[]{1, 4, 5})); // [4,4]
```

I got: `[4,1,4]`

When I changed the content of the first if to the following, everything worked fine:

```
  for (int n : numbers) {
    List<Integer> remainedCombination = bestSum_efficient(targetSum - n, numbers,map);
    if (remainedCombination != null) {
        List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<>();
        combination.add(n);
        combination.addAll(remainedCombination);

    if (shortestCombination == null || shortestCombination.size() > combination.size()) {
            shortestCombination = combination;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does creating a new combination list each in each iteration worked, while using the remainingCombination list that returned didn't?

Comment: maybe because you reverse the order? in the second situation it adds N in the beginning of the combination list and in the first one you add it to the end?

Comment: Better asked on [https://cs.stackexchange.com/](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Cool, never new about its existence. Will post it there too :)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I dont think its related to the order..

Comment: @MarkJeronimus i dont think its related to that forum, I know how to solve the issue, I think its an issue in the code..

Comment: Were you able to understand the root cause of this issue? I have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After squeezing my brain for a while, I think that I have found the root cause of this issue.

In the first scenario:

```
        List<Integer> remainedCombination = bestSum_efficient(targetSum - n, numbers,map);
        if (remainedCombination != null) {
            remainedCombination.add(n);
```

We modify directly the list `remainedCombination` by adding `n` at the end of it. This will actually modify the entry of the `HashMap` that we use for memoization, when the function `bestSum_efficient` returns the saved entry via the lines:

```
    if (map.containsKey(targetSum)) {
        return map.get(targetSum);
    }
```

as in this situation `remainedCombination` will be a reference to `map.get(targetSum)`, so doing `remainedCombination.add(n);` is the equivalent of doing `map.get(targetSum).add(n)`;

However we only want to modify the entries of the HashMap at the end of the `bestSum_efficient` function if we find a shortest way to reach the target sum and not directly in the `for` loop before checking the length condition  `if (shortestCombination == null || shortestCombination.size() > remainedCombination .size()) {`

In the 2nd (working) example, we create a new temporary `ArrayList`

```
        List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<>();
        combination.add(n);
        combination.addAll(remainedCombination);
```

before adding `n` there. This will therefore not affect the `HashMap` used for the memoization, that will only be modified just before the `return` of the function:

```
    map.put(targetSum, shortestCombination);
    return shortestCombination;
```